# NoneType error with Python class and function

Tags: python, class, nonetype, object-oriented-analysis

Despite my function returning an array, I get an `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` error. I first define classes, and then insert the function. 
I'm relatively new to Python, and would appreciate any help/comments.

The Classes are:

```
from scipy import array, dot, zeros, empty
from scipy.optimize import brentq
from numpy import *
from numpy.random import uniform 
from time import time

# from mpi4py import MPI

class UtilTheory:
    """

    """

    def utility(self, other):
        raise NotImplementedError("You need to implement method 'utility' "
                                  "in the child class.")

    def demand(self, p):
        raise NotImplementedError("You need to implement method 'demand' "
                                  "in the child class.")


    def excessDemand(self, p):
        p = array(p)
        return self.demand(p) - self.endowment

    def indUtility(self, p):
        x = self.demand(p)
        return self.utility(x)

    def __add__(self, other):
        economy = Economy([self, other])

        return economy

    def __radd__(self, other):
        economy = Economy([self] + other)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        economy = Economy(other * [self])

        return economy

class Consumer(UtilTheory, object):
    """
    Defines general features of a consumer
    """

    def __init__(self, endowment=array([1,1]), alpha=0.5, rho=0.0):
        self.endowment = array(endowment)
        self.alpha = float(alpha)
        self.rho = rho
        self.sigma = 1.0 / (1.0 - rho)

    def __str__(self):
        return ('e=' + str(self.endowment) +
                ', alpha=' + str(self.alpha) +
                ', rho=' + str(self.rho))

    def demand(self, p):
        endowment = self.endowment
        alpha = self.alpha
        sigma = self.sigma
        p = array(p)
        m = dot(endowment, p)

        x1 = ((alpha / p[0]) ** sigma * m /
              (alpha ** sigma * p[0] ** (1 - sigma) +
              (1 - alpha) ** sigma * p[1] ** (1 - sigma)))

        x2 = (((1.0 - alpha) / p[1]) ** sigma * m /
              (alpha ** sigma * p[0] ** (1 - sigma) +
              (1 - alpha) ** sigma * p[1] ** (1 - sigma)))

        return array([x1, x2])

    def utility(self, x):
        if self.rho != 0:
            return ((self.alpha * x[0] ** self.rho +
                    (1.0 - self.alpha) * x[1] ** self.rho) **
                       (1.0 / self.rho))

        return x[0] ** self.alpha * x[1] ** (1.0 - self.alpha)

class Economy:
    """
    Consists of consumers
    """

    def __init__(self, consumers):
        """
        Consumers should be a list of consumers
        """

        self.consumers = consumers

    def excessDemand(self, p):
        result = zeros(2)
        for consumer in self.consumers:
            result = result + consumer.excessDemand(p)

        return result

    def demand(self, p):
        result = zeros(2)
        for consumer in self.consumers:
            result = result + consumer.demand(p)

        return result

    def excessDemandGood0(self, p0):
        p = array([p0, 1.0 - p0])
        result = 0

        for consumer in self.consumers:
            result = result + consumer.excessDemand(p)[0]

        return result

    def __add__(self,other):
        try:
            return Economy(self.consumers + other.consumers)
        except:
            return Economy(self.consumers + [other])

    def numEquilibria(self, n=100):
        # p = array([p0, 1 - p0])
        q = linspace(0, 1, n)
        result = empty(len(q))
        #print result
        for i, p0 in enumerate(q):
            a = self.excessDemandGood0(p0)
            #print a
            result[i] = a
        index = zeros(len(q))

        for i in range(1, 2):
            if result[i] <= 0:  
                index[i - 1] = 1
            else: 
                index[i - 1] = 0

        for i in range(2, n - 1):
            test=result[i - 1] * result[i]
            #print test
            if test <= 0:
                index[i - 1] = 1
            else:
                index[i - 1] = 0

        for i in range(n - 2, n - 1):
            if result[i] > 0:
                index[i - 1] = 1
            else:
                index[i - 1] = 0

        count = sum(index)
        # print "The number of equilibria is"
        return count
        # print "Excess Demand funciton on the grid:"
        # print result
        # print "Index when excess demand goes from possitive to negative"
        # print index

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        economy = Economy(other * self.consumers)

        return economy

    def equilibrium(self, startbracket=None):
        def g(x):
            return self.excessDemandGood0(x)

        if startbracket == None:
            startbracket = [1e-10, 1-1e-10]

        eqPrice1 = brentq(g, startbracket[0], startbracket[1])

        return array([eqPrice1, 1 - eqPrice1])

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.consumers)

    def __str__(self):
        resultString = 'Economy with ' + str(len(self)) + ' consumers.\n'

        for consumer in self.consumers:
            resultString = resultString + str(consumer) + '\n'

        return resultString
```

I get the error when implementing the following `stats()` function which calls on `randomEconEq()`:

```
def randomEcon(e1=[1, 0], e2=[0, 1], iterate_max=100):
    rho1 = random.uniform(-8, -1)
    rho2 = random.uniform(-8, -1)
    alpha1 = random.uniform(0, 1)
    alpha2 = random.uniform(0, 1)
    x = Consumer(endowment=e1, alpha=alpha1, rho=rho1)
    y = Consumer(endowment=e2, alpha=alpha2, rho=rho2)
    econ = Economy([x, y])
    return econ

def randomEconEq(iterate_max=100):
    iterate = 0
    eq_vec = []
    start = time()
    while iterate < iterate_max:
        iterate += 1
        econ = randomEcon()
        equilibria = econ.numEquilibria()
        eq_vec.append(equilibria)
        # print eq_vec
        if (econ.numEquilibria() > 1):
            print "Number of multiple equilibria is " + \
                                                str(econ.numEquilibria())
            print str(econ)
            print str(eq_vec)

    end = time()
    totaltime = end - start
    #print('Total Time is ' + str(totaltime))
    return eq_vec

def stats(eq_vec, iterate_max):
    one_eq = zeros(len(eq_vec))
    three_eq = zeros(len(eq_vec))
    five_eq = zeros(len(eq_vec))
    more_eq = zeros(len(eq_vec))
    # print (eq_vec)

    for i in range(len(eq_vec)):
        if eq_vec[i] == 1:
            one_eq[i] = 1

        if eq_vec[i] == 3:
            three_eq[i] = 1

        if eq_vec[i] == 5:
            five_eq[i] = 1

        if eq_vec[i] > 5:
            more_eq[i] = 1

    Eq1 = sum(one_eq)
    Eq3 = sum(three_eq)
    Eq5 = sum(five_eq)
    EqMore = sum(more_eq)

    prob1 = float((Eq1 / iterate_max) * 100)
    prob3 = float((Eq3 / iterate_max) * 100)
    prob5 = float((Eq5 / iterate_max) * 100)
    probMore = float((EqMore/iterate_max) * 100)

    print ('The Vector of the number of equililbria is:' + str(eq_vec))
    print ('Probability of 1 equilibrium is (percent) ' + str(prob1))
    print ('Probability of 3 equilibria is (percent) ' + str(prob3))
    print ('Probability of 5 equilibria is (percent) ' + str(prob5))
    print ('Probability of 1 equilibria is (percent) ' + str(probMore))

eq_vec = randomEconEq(100)
stats(eq_vec, 100)
```

The error appears in the last two lines of code when implementing the function `stats()`.

An example which creates the error is:

```
stats(randomEconEq(100), 100)
```

and the complete traceback is:

```
>>> stats(randomEconEq(100), 100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Creating a minimal example that shows the problem would greatly help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Also your indentation in the question is incorrect and would cause errors if anyone attempted to run it.

Comment: It would also help if you showed the *complete* traceback.

Comment: UtilTheory.__radd__ is not returning a value (so is implicitly returning None).

Comment: I've fixed source (waiting for edit to be approved), and it seems to work for me. I've did full analysis of your code — you have several wrong calculations (like in `prob1 = float((Eq1 / iterate_max) * 100)` — it should have been `prob1 = 100.0 * Eq1 / iterate_max`) and style issues (don't use `str()`, use `.format()` instead; don't use camelCase; don't build strings incrementally and so on), but nothing should raise `TypeError` because of calling `None`.

Comment: It's total guesswork, but from stack trace it seems that execution didn't step in function at all. So either `stats` or `randomEconEq` is `None`, it isn't deeper. I bet it's `stats` because it's easy to reassign in REPL.

Comment: If you want the ability to debug this step by step, look into [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/). It's a fully featured Python development environment, and it might shed some light through its own brand of Intellisense about what may be going wrong. It's my favorite Python IDE. You can also step into functions, use breakpoints, etc with it.

Comment: @modchan Thanks a lot for editing the post and for your response. I did include return statements in stats function and it now works.  Thanks again for your help and I would appreciate an up vote (been coding for only 6 months!) This is embarrassing, but how to properly include the indentation in a post? (I mess it up every time when I include code here).

Comment: @KymikoLoco Thanks for letting me know about PyCharm! I'll look into it.

Comment: @k1000ahenao, if you managed to resolve your question, then post an answer yourself and accept it, that would help others who run into similar issue later. Please, prune your question source to the bare minimum that reproduces your exception, because now `stats()` function does not need `return`, because it's result isn't used anywhere — which misleads others because you have seemingly shared the unrelated code.